# xfwm4 themes gone in debian bullseye?

Tags: debian, testing

After updating my debian testing to bullseye, the xfce theme completely vanished. I had a dark them (forgot name) and now its Raleigh as the only theme installed. xfwm4-themes seem to exist only in jessie? Where are they gone?

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bullseye&searchon=names&keywords=xfwm4-themes

Comment: I have no idea what happened to `xfwm4-themes`, but the `mate-themes` package has several themes that work nicely with xfwm4.  I use `TraditionalOk`.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1184245/248158